# Use SQL view in .NET MVC Entity Framework application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Current code:

```
 <dd>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Contact.isPremierEligible, new { @disabled = "disabled" })

    @{
        bool eligible = false;
        MyApp.Models.StatisticEntities statsDB = new MyApp.Models.StatisticEntities();
        IList<MyApp.Models.Stat> stats = statsDB.Stats.Where(x => x.AmtCollected >= 40000 && x.ContactID == Model.Contact.ContactID).ToList();
        if (stats != null && stats.Count > 0)
        { 
            eligible = true;
            }
        }
        @if (eligible && !Model.Contact.isPremierEligible)
        {
            <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="bg-success">ELIGIBLE</span>
        }
 </dd>
```

I need to replace the criteria for "eligible" to instead use a SQL view which I will call "dbo.qyEligibleView" which I have already created.

How do I do this in .NET? I've been tasked this by the company as I am the database administrator but changing the .NET application code in Visual Studio is outside my expertise area.  I know enough to identify the above code block as what needs to be modified but don't know beyond that how I would replace this with the SQL view I created.

The relevant portion of the SQL view is:

```
WHERE 
    (CONVERT(datetime, Stats.StatDate, 102) >= DATEADD(d, - 119, CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) 
    AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01' AS DATETIME))) 
    AND (Contact.Premier <> 1) 
    AND (Contact.ContactType = 'CLIENT') 
    AND (Stats.AmtCollected > 40000) 
    AND (ContactNameLink.[Primary] = 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am a novice at editing this, so would I replace a portion of the code above?  Or leave this as is but modify the view referenced in the model?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all info into a view, as you did, to not have 2 views.
Then use the merged view.

I mean The model should contain the field you need

but you can pass it also by **ViewBag**, not recommended because you may send too much unused information or redundant

in your controller, before returning the View

```
ViewBag.EligibleView = dbo.qyEligibleView;
```

On the top of your view, add

```
@{
    IEnumerable<qyEligibleView>  eligibleView = ViewBag.EligibleView;
}
```

then you can use easily the `@eligibleView`, you can do query with it